# Left factors $L$ of Dyck paths such that $L$ has $n-1$ up steps

Tags: catalan-numbers

From Stanley's Catalan Numbers, problem 28:

Left factors $L$ of Dyck paths such that $L$ has $n-1$ up steps.

I don't understand what this means. If after a sequence of ups, there are equal number or fewer downs, then for $n=4$, I got $13$ paths, not $14$:

uuu/uuud/uuudd/uuuddd
uudu/uudud/uuddu/uuddud
uduu/uduud/uduudd
ududu/ududud

Can anyone explain? Thanks.

Comment: Any such left factor with $n-1$ ups and $n-k\le n-1$ downs can be completed to a Dyck path of semilength $n$ by appending $ud^k=ud\dots d$ with $k\ge 1$ downs at the end. This is a bijection, since any Dyck path ends with a well-defined suffix $ud^k$ with $k\ge 1$ downs.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein That is correct. I overinterpreted the $L$ and unfortunately the illustration in the book for $n=3$ does not clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We consider the Dyck paths of length $2n$ and take $L$ as a valid left factor if it contains $n-1$ ups. We then have to add the blue left path in the case $n=4$ in the second row and get $C_4=14$ paths.
\begin{align*}
uudu/uudud/\color{blue}{uududd}/uuddu/uuddud   
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry, my interpretation was, suppose $u_i$ and $d_i$ are the numbers of straight ups and downs respectively, then a path $u_1d_1u_2d_2\cdots$ satisfies $\sum u_i=n-1$ and $d_i\leq u_i$ (I suppose $L$ refers to this, longer l and shorter _?). The path $uududd$ does not satisfy it.

Comment: @HaoranChen: I've added an interpretation.

Comment: Thank you! I overinterpreted the $L$ and unfortunately the illustration in the book for $n=3$ does not clarify it.

Comment: @HaoranChen: You're welcome! :-)